# Tips for strong typed xml attribute composition (builder)

Tags: xml, swift

I'm working on a xml builder that conforms to specific attribute restrictions in it's elements. For example, this Person element's only valid attribute would be "gender" and the value can only be "male" or "female."

Right now, I'm using a `[String:String]` for attribute key/values. I'd like a strongly typed way to force these restrictions per each unique element attribute requirement.

I'm at a loss for a Swift way of doing this. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
extension XmlBuilder {
    func person(text: String? = "", attributes: [String:String] = [String:String]()) -> XmlBuilder {
        fn = compose(fn, { doc in
            doc.root.addChild(name: "Person", value: text, attributes: attributes)
            return doc
        })
        return self
    }
}

let xml = XmlBuilder()
    .person("Jon", attributes: ["gender":"male"])
    .construct()
```

Comment: When you say 'conforms to specific attributes' what do you mean? Do you mean using an XML schema, or do you mean something else? Bear in mind that all XML attributes are Strings, so any time you want to convert to/from a different type you need to use a converter one way or another.

Comment: Updated for more clarity, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having a typesafe XML builder, you should probably think about constructing your object model in a typesafe way, and then have that render itself into XML either internally or externally.

So you could have:

```
enum Gender { case Male, Female }
struct Person { let name:String; let gender:Gender }
```

You can then create them in a typesafe way:

```
Person(name:"alblue", gender: .Male)
```

And then walk over the elements to generate an XML element, or add a toXML method that returns a String containing the elements. You could integrate this into a builder if there's a protocol that all your data structures inherit from that allow them to be converted. But you'd have to use an interim typesafe data structure that would allow you to do this instead of a generic dictionary.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'll do. Thanks

Comment: I found this [link](http://alisoftware.github.io/swift/enum/json/2015/07/16/swift-enums-for-JSON-parsing/) which is relevant to AlBlue's suggestion but uses JSON.